# Solr one field has different values based on some conditions

Tags: solr

I use Solr to index and search on a system with about 100,000 products and 300,000 users. The field to index is "price". But for each user, the price may be different.
For example:
- For Product1 and User1, User2.
- User1 sees the Product1's price 100$. 
- But User2 cannot not see the price (User2 has to fulfill some conditions to see the price) although User2 still sees Product1 when searching.

At the time of indexing, we cannot determine to set the price for a specific user or not. The product has a flag called "Required Contract". And when a user log in, we will check if the user has applied the "contract" for that product to show or hide the price. 
The straight forward solution for this problem is to create different "price" fields for each user. So when indexing, we loop through the list of users and index the "price" field for that user. And when searching, we use the correct "price" field for the login user. Obviously, this is not a practical solution.

My question is how to index "price" field in this case or is there any other approaches on the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have specific prices for each user, but for groups of users. Presumably a not-very-high number of unique groups. If so, a simple solution is to have multiple price fields (`price_group_1`, `price_group_2`, ...), one for each user group, and let your display-code show the one matching the users group.

Comment: Thanks @Toke for your answer. But It's quite challenge for my problem is that conditions are determined by the time of searching (by combining some products attributes and user's ones) not at indexing. So groups seem not to be helpful in this case.

Comment: @Kien Please expand your question with relevant details on how you determine which price is relevant then, otherwise it won't be possible to even suggest a solution for how you can index it in a decent way.

Comment: @MatsLindh I have updated my question to clarify the requirement. Hope that help to clear the problem to suggest the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a while I came up with 2 solutions:

1/ The first one is to duplicate a document that requires the condition. The duplicated document contains no price (or any value assigned to it). Because the numbers of documents requiring conditions are not too much so duplicating is not a waste of resources. So when doing a searching, by combining some other flags the result is the duplicated documents not the original one that fulfill my requirements.

2/ Another approach is using [Function Queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries). I figured this out by searching on Google for my problem as I didn't know about that feature at the beginning.

Hope that can help someone's problems!